# Ruby file won't run in Max OSX Terminal. syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby, terminal, osx-mavericks

Using:

- RVM 1.26.0
- Ruby 2.1.4
- OSX Mavericks 10.9.5
- TextEdit
- Terminal

I'm working on the Learn to Code Ruby The Hard Way tutorial. This is the first program.

```
puts "Hello World!"
puts "Hello Again"
puts "I like typing this."
puts "This is fun."
puts "Yay! Printing."
puts "I'd must rather you 'not'."
puts 'I "said" do not touch this.'
```

This is what comes up in Terminal.

```
ex1.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
puts 'I "said" do not touch this."
```

I have a Nitrious.io account and the file runs perfectly on it. I have searched for an answer, but all of the other questions involve more complicated programs with solutions that don't seem to apply to something as simple as this. It is my understanding that Terminal should just print these with no issues. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The problem is on your system, as the code runs fine on mine. You don't show how you tried to run the code, which could be a clue. Also, I'd recommend not using TextEdit to edit code. It *can* do it, but it doesn't have the capabilities you'll need for the long haul. I highly recommend [vim](http://www.vim.org) and/or [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com). They're mainstays for development and can run on multiple OSes, including Mac OS. Use [macvim](https://code.google.com/p/macvim/) on Mac OS. Sublime is more mouse oriented, but macvim does a decent job with it too.

Comment: I ran the code by typing `ruby ex1.rb` which was the name of the file. I closed TextWrangler and rewrote it again there. It worked! It still won't run from a file written in TextEdit though. Why it doesn't work in TextEdit is something I'd very much like to know... just because I find it interesting!

Answer (score 0):

If you copy pasted the code exactly, your issue is the quotes. They need to be the standard " instead of what you have (“). This happens all the time when copy pasting from blogs that automatically change over " to open/close double quotes.

Comment: I'm typing it myself, not copying and pasting. Or else what would be the point, right? : D The formatting you mentioned is done automatically by Stack Overflow

Comment: Looks like TextEdit now defaults to rich text documents, maybe thats your issue? When I try to type your code in textedit the quotes get automatically changed to the incorrect ones.

Comment: Thanks for going the extra mile! But you can select "Make Plain Text" under the Format pulldown menu. While it's in Rich Text mode you can't save with the .rb extension. I also rewrote it in TextWrangler and it still didn't work. I feel like it could be a problem with my system.

Comment: That being said, I'm too new to coding to have any idea what that problem might be, ha ha.

Answer (score 0):

TextEdit is trying to convert your quotes. It converts `"foo"` to `“foo”`, i.e., `\x201cfoo\x201d`.

It also doesn't offer a text format, only RTF and Word formats making it unsuitable for programming.

Comment: You're right! I disabled Smart quotes and now it works. However, it does offer a plain text format that is configurable. It may not be the best option, but I like to learn how to use the worst so that I can appreciate the more advanced options at my disposal. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with the Preferences in TextEdit I found the answer. In Preferences > New Document I unchecked the boxes in the bottom right corner that said "Smart quotes" and "Smart dashes." It works now. But I do appreciate your help and showing interest in my question!

Comment: You're correct that those two need to be turned off, but I'd recommend almost all the options be turned off. The fewer things it does in an attempt to help you will be better in the long run. A word-processing editor, which is what TextEdit is, has very few features in common with a good text-editing editor such as vim, emacs, Sublime Text, etc.

Answer (score 0):

try using %(Hello World) even I faced similar issues with string delimiter. Now moving to sublime text